# Laravel Query Builder Advance Where

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Laravel Advance Query Builder not seeing parent method variable

```
 public function read($status=null,$skip=0,$take=10,$orderby=array()) 
 {

    $table = DB::table('users')
                ->skip($skip)
                ->take($take)
                ->where(function($query) {

                 if($status)
                    $query->where('status','!=',$status);

                });
  }
```

This returns an error which $status variable undefined inside the advance where query. Is there anything to extend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use variables in your closure, you must include them.

Change

```
->where(function($query) {
```

to

```
->where(function($query) use ($status) {
```

Comment: Thank you. use - is new to me.

Comment: I wish I would seen this answer a month ago, thanks.